# Many to many field Multiselect Into Dropdown List

Tags: django

I have one many-to-many field in one of my models which is currently coming as Multiselect but I need a dropdown where users can select multiple values as I have huge data to show.

I am trying this in **forms.py** but it is not showing the dropdown field.

**model.py**:

```
class Chain(models.Model):
    chain_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    chain_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    chain_type = models.ForeignKey(ChainType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('chain_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.chain_name



class Brg(models.Model):
    brg_campaign_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    campaign_tracking = models.ForeignKey(CampaignTracking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brg_name = models.ForeignKey(Chain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="primary_brg",
    help_text='Add Brgs/chain names for these above campaign has run')
    brg_benchmark = models.ManyToManyField(Chain, related_name="competitor_brg", null=True,
    blank=True, help_text='Add max.5 other benchmarks brgs to check overall impact')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Brg Campaign Tracking'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Brg names list"
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ChainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model: Chain
        # fields = ('campaign_tracking', 'brg_name', 'brg_benchmark',)
        widgets = {'chain_name': Select()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `django-ajax-selects` library

https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects/

Define a lookup channel:

## yourapp/lookups.py

```
from ajax_select import register, LookupChannel
from .models import Tag

@register('tags')
class TagsLookup(LookupChannel):

    model = Tag

    def get_query(self, q, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).order_by('name')[:50]

    def format_item_display(self, item):
        return u"<span class='tag'>%s</span>" % item.name
```

Add field to a form:

## yourapp/forms.py

```
from ajax_select.fields import AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField

class DocumentForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Document

    tags = AutoCompleteSelectMultipleField('tags')
```

Comment: thanks, at first I was trying to figure out by changing in widgets `Select() to SelectMultiple()`. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple). But is currently in `SelectMultiple()`

Comment: I'm not sure what Tag is. Is it something built-in?

Comment: no, it is a sample Model